# Accepting either mutable and immutable generic types with traits in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, traits, rust-sqlx

I am using Rust with sqlx and postgres to build a REST API. I am trying to build a `Database` struct which has a generic connection param in it.

```
struct Database<T>
where
    T: Sync + Send,
    for<'a> &'a T: sqlx::Executor<'a, Database = Postgres>,
{
  conn: T
}
```

`T` would be owned by the struct, and `&T` is expected to implement `Executor` trait.

I am able to use `Pool<Postgres>` as `T`, since `&Pool<Postgres>` implements the `Executor`.

What I want is (and this is the reason I made the `conn` a generic type) to be able to use `Transaction<Postgres>` as `T`. But the problem is that `&Transaction<Postgres>` does not implement the `Executor` trait, but `&mut Transaction<Postgres>` does.

The reason I want to do this is there are CRUD functions that I want to be able to use with both a transaction and a pool connection. And I don't want to write duplicate code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone has a better idea, but it seems the following could work.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use sqlx::{Pool, Transaction, Postgres};

trait Connection<'a>: Sync + Send {
    type Executor: sqlx::Executor<'a>;
    fn executor(&'a mut self) -> Self::Executor;
}

impl <'a> Connection<'a> for Pool<Postgres> {
    type Executor = &'a Self;
    fn executor(&'a mut self) -> Self::Executor {
        &*self
    }
}

impl <'c> Connection<'c> for Transaction<'c, Postgres> {
    type Executor = &'c mut Self;
    fn executor(&'c mut self) -> Self::Executor {
        self
    }
}

struct Database<'a, T: Connection<'a>>
{
    conn: T,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>
}

impl <'a, T: Connection<'a>> Database<'a, T> {
    fn q(&'a mut self) {
        let _: T::Executor = self.conn.executor();
        // sqlx::query!("Some query").execute(self.conn.executor())
    }
}
```

At the very least it [compiles](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Asqlx%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%220.6.3%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%20%22runtime-tokio-native-tls%22%2C%20%22postgres%22%20%5D%20%7D%0A*%2F%0Ause%20std%3A%3Amarker%3A%3APhantomData%3B%0Ause%20sqlx%3A%3A%7BPool%2C%20Transaction%2C%20Postgres%7D%3B%0A%0Atrait%20Connection%3C%27a%3E%3A%20Sync%20%2B%20Send%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Executor%3A%20sqlx%3A%3AExecutor%3C%27a%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20executor(%26%27a%20mut%20self)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AExecutor%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3C%27a%3E%20Connection%3C%27a%3E%20for%20Pool%3CPostgres%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Executor%20%3D%20%26%27a%20Self%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20executor(%26%27a%20mut%20self)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AExecutor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26*self%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3C%27c%3E%20Connection%3C%27c%3E%20for%20Transaction%3C%27c%2C%20Postgres%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Executor%20%3D%20%26%27c%20mut%20Self%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20executor(%26%27c%20mut%20self)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AExecutor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Database%3C%27a%2C%20T%3A%20Connection%3C%27a%3E%3E%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20conn%3A%20T%2C%0A%20%20%20%20phantom%3A%20PhantomData%3C%26%27a%20T%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3C%27a%2C%20T%3A%20Connection%3C%27a%3E%3E%20Database%3C%27a%2C%20T%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20q(%26%27a%20mut%20self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20_%3A%20T%3A%3AExecutor%20%3D%20self.conn.executor()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20sqlx%3A%3Aquery!(%22Some%20query%22).execute(self.conn.executor())%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%22)%3B%0A%7D) :)

Comment: This is great! This works with no problem for impl blocks `impl Database<'static, Pool<Postgres>>` and `impl<'a> Database<'a, Transaction<'a, Postgres>>`. But when I try to implement functionality that are common to both pool and transaction it does not work. I tried this: `impl<'a, T> PostgresDb<'a, T> where T: Connection<'a>`. When I do `query!("Some query").execute(&self.conn)`, it say Executor not implemented for T.

Comment: You'll need to add a method to the trait returning a `Self::Executor` and use it instead of `&` in that code. If you figure it out, add a comment; otherwise I can try tomorrow.

Comment: Or maybe this doesn't work, because the method would need to take `&Self` for `Pool` and `&mut Self` for `Transaction`. You could also have a method taking `Self` which would work for both but only get you a single query :(

Comment: @AhmetYazıcı Maybe you don't need `T` to be owned by the `Database` structure, and it can just contain the correct kind of reference from the beginning?

Comment: The last comment of yours seems to be the only way to do it. Passing directly `&Pool` or `&mut Transaction` to create the Database instance. This way T will be required to implement the `Executor` trait directly. The slight problem of this is that, Database with pool connection can not directly create a transaction from its member function. When I wanna use a transaction connection in a function, I have to get the pool connection within the business logic, create a transaction, and create a new instance of Database with that transaction connection. But that's a necessary overhead I think.

Comment: Actually, see a new simpler attempt. Can't test it fully because `query!` won't compile on Rust Explorer, but I'd expect it can be made to work.